# Async Get Queried Data and Page by Page

Tags: ignite

I notice that in ignite source code they have QueryPager that is included in some QueryCursor classes, but they don't expose the getter for this pager field.

I'm curious if ignite support async query and the data is returned page by page, similar to BigQuery so that my application can deal with the first page of data and ignite gets next page at the same time, which saves time when querying large amount of data.